# How to apply a condition to a large number of columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to eliminate all rows that are equal to a certain values (or in a certain range) within a dataframe with a large number of columns. For example, if I had the following dataframe:

```
    a  b
 0  1  0
 1  2  1
 2  3  2
 3  0  3
```

and wanted to remove all rows containing 0, I could use:

```
a_df[(a_df['a'] != 0) & (a_df['b'] !=0)]
```

but this becomes a pain when you're dealing with a large number of columns. It could be done as:

```
for i in a_df.columns.values:
    a_df = a_df[a_df[i] != 0]
```

but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it for the whole df and call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
In [45]:
df[df != 0].dropna()

Out[45]:
   a  b
1  2  1
2  3  2
```

The condition `df != 0` produces a boolean mask:

```
In [47]:    
df != 0

Out[47]:
       a      b
0   True  False
1   True   True
2   True   True
3  False   True
```

When this is combined with the df it produces `NaN` values where the condition is not met:

```
In [48]:
df[df != 0]

Out[48]:
    a   b
0   1 NaN
1   2   1
2   3   2
3 NaN   3
```

Calling `dropna` drops any row with a `NaN` value

Comment: @DSM yes, just reread the question, just needs a call to `dropna`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of EdChum's approach.  You could do `df != 0` and then use `all` to make your selector:

```
>>> (df != 0).all(axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

and then use this to select:

```
>>> df.loc[(df != 0).all(axis=1)]
   a  b
1  2  1
2  3  2
```

The advantage of this is that it keeps NaNs if you want, e.g.

```
>>> df
   a   b
0  1   0
1  2 NaN
2  3   2
3  0   3
>>> df.loc[(df != 0).all(axis=1)]
   a   b
1  2 NaN
2  3   2
>>> df[(df != 0)].dropna()
   a  b
2  3  2
```

Answer (score 0):

as you've mentioned in your question you may need to drop rows that have a value in a certain range you can do this by the following

suppose the range is `0 , 10 , 20`

```
frame = DataFrame({'b': [4, 7, -3, 2], 'a': [0, 1, 0, 1]})
mask = frame.applymap(lambda x : False if x in [0 , 10 , 20] else True )
frame[mask.all(axis = 1)]
```